# Form select in drupal ctools multistep form

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, multi-step

I'm trying to use drupal ctools multistep wizard function for creating multistep form, and I have problem with select element.

```
mymodule_multi_form_start($form, &$form_state) { 
    $form['from'] = array(
'#title' => t('from'),
'#type' => 'select',
'#maxlength' => 40,
'#options' => $from_options,
'#default_value' => isset($form_state['object']->from) ? $from_options[$form_state['object']->from] : $from_options_first,
);
}
```

After submit I always have the first option in the select list.
If I use `'#required' => TRUE,` I have some error, because I can't move to the next step.
What do I wrong? Or maybe is it error of ctools multistep wizard?

Comment: It doesn't work with changed fields by javascript.

Comment: You can implement hook_field_widget_form to build multi select list. I can show my code if you want to follow this approach :)

Comment: I'll be glad if you show your code. Thank you

Comment: please have a look on this, let me know If you have any query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39405925/cascaded-select-list-as-a-custom-field-using-hook-field-widget-form-in-drupal-7/39615299#39615299

Comment: Did it help you ?

Comment: Yes, I did it thank you

Comment: then please upvote my answer in above link, thanks

Comment: I'd like to do it, but have no enough reputation